# jQuery flot draw realtime linechart with time series data

Tags: jquery, flot, linechart

1. totalPoints = 300
2. my dataset formate is like this [[new Date().getTime(), Math.random()*100], ...]
3. everytime updating the dataset, dataset.shift(), dataset.push([new data])

I am new to javascript and my problem is：
  1. When set the options of xaxis {mode: "time"}(jquery.flot.time.js is imported), it even does not draw any points.
  2. When xaxis options is only {show: true}, it draw a chart that missing from left to right but virtually the datase is refreshing(shift and push is going right) instead of updating like moving from right to write.
  3. http://www.pureexample.com/ExampleTesterII-123.html this site gave a demo but i can not run it locally(I am sure having import the same js, css, html files), if anybody run it locally successfully please tell me.

Thanks, guys.

Here are some code I've been working.

```
var data = [],
    totalPoints = 100;
var updateInterval = 30;
var now = new Date().getTime();
var dataset;

function getMyData(){
    data.shift();
    while( data.length < totalPoints){
        var y = Math.random() * 100;
        data.push([now += updateInterval, y]);
    }
    return data;
}

var option;
option = {
    series: {
        shadowSize: 0,  // Drawing is faster without shadows
        lines: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: 1.2,
            fill: true
        }
    },
    yaxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
            if (v % 10 == 0) {
                return v + "%";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        show: true,
        mode: "time",
        tickSize: [2, "second"],
        tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
            var date = new Date(v);

            if (date.getSeconds() % 20 == 0) {
                var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() :     date.getHours();
                var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
                var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();

                return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }};

$(document).ready(function(){
    data = getMyData();

    var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [{label: "Label", data: data}], option);
    plot.draw();

    function update(){
        plot.setData([getMyData()]);
        plot.draw();

        setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
    }

    update();
});
```

Comment: show some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the official real-time updates example? It is also bundled with the download: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html

Comment: The example I have gone through several times. I am going to stick some code here, anyway, thank u for helping.